# Replace a text ${abc} in a variable with another variable text in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
FIRST=$(cat <<-END
abc,def
END
)

SECOND=$(cat <<-END
local list=${list}
END
)
```

I want to replace ${list} with variable FIRST using shell script, i tried this but it works with replacing a text in file not variable
RES=$(echo "$SECOND" | sed "s|${list}|$FIRST|")

result should be:
local list = abc,def

Comment: Just use `list=$FIRST` in the here doc, or alternatively set `list=$FIRST` before the declaration of `SECOND`. Variables in the here doc will be expanded.

Comment: `SECOND="local list=$FIRST"`. Why do you need a `cat` for this simple case?